# A transversal for the $\operatorname{Ad}(K)$ action on a sphere in $\mathfrak{p}$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, ergodic-theory, root-systems

This exercise level question has been unanswered on MSE for a few years. I hope you can answer it either [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/958531/why-do-adk-orbits-in-the-1-eigenspace-of-a-cartan-decomposition-intersect-t) or here.

$G$ is a semisimple Lie group with a choice of Cartan decomposition on its Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{k} \oplus \mathfrak{p}$. 
The Cartan involution also induces an inner product on $\mathfrak{g}$ and we denote the sphere in $\mathfrak{p}$ by $\mathfrak{p}_1$.
Let $K$ be the connected subgroup associated to $\mathfrak{k}$ and let $\mathfrak{a}\subset \mathfrak{p}$ be a maximal abelian subalgebra.

The action of $\mathfrak{a}$ on $\mathfrak{g}$ gives rise to a root system $\Sigma$ on $\mathfrak{a}^*$.
Fix a notion of positivity here and let 
$$\mathfrak{a}^+ := \lbrace H \in \mathfrak{a}: \lambda(H)>0 \text{ for all } \lambda \in \Sigma^+\rbrace$$

**Question:** Why is it that the unit vectors in ${\mathfrak{a}^+}$ is a transversal for the adjoint action of $K$ on $\mathfrak{p}_1$?
More precisely, for every $X \in \mathfrak{p}_1$, there is a unique unit vector $H$ in $\overline{\mathfrak{a}^+}$ which is in the $K$-orbit of $X$.

$\mathfrak{p} = \bigcup \operatorname{Ad}(k)\mathfrak{a}$, coincidence of the analytic Weyl group and algebraic Weyl group, and the fact that $\overline{\mathfrak{a}^+}$ is a fundamental domain for the algebraic Weyl group acting on $\mathfrak{a}$, together imply that each $K$ orbit in $\mathfrak{p}$ passes through at least once. But it's not yet clear to me why two unit vectors in $\overline{\mathfrak{a}^+}$ cannot be related by some $k \in K\smallsetminus N_K(\mathfrak{a})$.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: As an intersection of 2 open subsets

Comment: Open in $\mathfrak{a}$? $g\mathfrak{a}^+$ might not be contained in $\mathfrak{a}$, right?

Comment: Oops sorry, it's not open. I'm not used to "fundamental domain" in such context, would you way what it means exactly for $D=\overline{\mathfrak{a}^+}$ to be a fundamental domain? It ought to mean that for every $g\in K-\{1\}$ we have $gD\cap D$ is small, but in which sense exactly? (it's not empty, since it contains zero and I'd guess it may contain more than zero) does it mean it's contained in the relative boundary of $D$ (boundary of $D$ in $\mathfrak{a}$)?

Comment: I made an edit. Does the question make sense?

Comment: It seems that you are acting on a cone, not a sphere, right?

Comment: @LSpice both. OP passed to the 1-sphere to avoid intersections, but in the original setting, the question can currently be stated as: is it true that every $K$-orbit in $\mathfrak{p}$ meets the closure of $\mathfrak{a}^+$ in a singleton.

Comment: Things are clear to me now. Just to clarify my previous confusion: if a group $G$ acts on a set $X$, a *transversal* is a subset $Y$ meeting each orbit in a singleton (that is, $Y$ meets every orbit and no two elements of $Y$ are in the same orbit). Strictly speaking, a *fundamental domain* is $Y\subset X$ such that the $(gY)_{g\in G}$ partition $X$ (this is much stronger and does not always exist). Practically, one uses to relax the condition that the $gY$ are disjoint to: they have "small" intersection. Here $Y$ is closed convex; small can mean: of dimension $<\dim(Y)$.

Comment: I understand now. This is why you previously made the comment ‘an uncountable group can’t have a fundamental domain of positive measure’? I’ll now use the word ‘transversal’. Also, I wasn’t sure whether to state the question in terms of the full cone or the unit vectors there. Both are equivalent since Ad(k) preserves length.

Comment: It's a good question. I'd suggest not to delete and rather post and accept a community-wiki answer linking to the MSE answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/958531/why-do-adk-orbits-in-the-1-eigenspace-of-a-cartan-decomposition-intersect-t/3678116#3678116) on MSE.

FYI, this is Theorem 4.21 (without proof) on page 74 in [Bekka and Mayer - Ergodic theory and topological dynamics of group actions on homogeneous spaces](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/ergodic-theory-and-topological-dynamics-of-group-actions-on-homogeneous-spaces/D44A57C1D660059C5C4AA7FA8E244659).